# spark write parquet to HDFS very slow on multi node

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs, parquet

i run well a spark submit with `--master local[*]`,

but when i run the spark submit on my multinode cluster 
`--master ip of master:port --deploy-mode client` :
my app run well until writing to HDFS into parquet, it doesn't stop, no error messages, nothing, still running..
i detected in the app the blocking part, it's :

```
resultDataFrame.write.parquet(path)
```

i tried 
with

```
resultDataFrame.repartition(1).write.parquet(path)
```

but still the same...

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: You might want to provide more details. While `repartition(1)` or `coalesce(1)` is asking for troubles, the code without it should work fine, as long as a) configuration is OK, b) there is no problem upstream.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to see you are trying to use master as local[*], which will run spark job in local mode and unable to use cluster resources.

If you are running spark job on cluster, you can look for spark submit options such as, master as yarn and deploy mode is cluster, here command mentioned below.

> spark-submit --class  **--master yarn --deploy-mode
>   cluster ** --conf = ... # other options 
>    [application-arguments]

once you run spark job with yarn master and deploy mode as cluster it will try to utilize all cluster resources.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. In fact it works well in local[*]. But in cluster mode, i have 3 VM, with my master, and 2 slaves and in my spark submit i gave in --master the ip of the master VM. It runs on all VMs,  until the write to HDFS part... 
Does really yarn could fix it ?

Comment: Definitely it will works, as its resource manager in cluster it will try to see number of resources in cluster and try to run job in parallel manner.

Comment: As you are using local[*], it will try to create multiple thread and try to run process on single machine not on entire cluster. You need yarn to run jobs on cluster to make better utilization of cluster resources.